# why python give me this error?[KeyError : 'left']

Tags: python-3.x

the error is

```
'#slider-image-{0}:target ~ .image-holder{left: {1} px;}'.format(times, (times - 1) * -800))
KeyError: 'left''
```

in this loop:

```
for file in file_read:
    file_write.write(
        '#slider-image-{0}:target ~ .image-holder{left {1} px;}'.format(times, (times - 1) * -800))
```

why this error happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: replace `{left {1} px;}` to `left {1} px`;

Comment: Because you have a placeholder named `left`: `{left: {1} px;}`. Double braces you don't mean to be placeholders.

Comment: @Artier: no, because the `{` and `}` have meaning in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a placeholder named `{left: ...}` in your format. That you meant that to be CSS syntax doesn't matter to Python. Escape the braces by doubling them:

```
file_write.write(
    '#slider-image-{0}:target ~ .image-holder{{left {1} px;}}'.format(times, (times - 1) * -800))
```

Doubled `{` and `}` braces are output as single braces:

```
>>> '{{left {0}}}'.format('demo')
'{left demo}'
```